# A grammar that accepts the empty set by the rule S->S

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

This was a homework assignment problem which I know I have incorrectly answered.  I gave:

```
S -> ''
```

meaning that S yields the empty string.  I know that the empty set and empty string are not the same.  According to my professor, the answer is:

```
S -> S
```

Now, that answer seems strange to me:

1. It will never terminate.
2. It isn't so much a language as the absence of one.

I understand from a strictly mathematical standpoint, I'm not going to get anywhere with number two.  However, is it required for a language to terminate?  Having a language that CAN go on forever sounds okay, but one that never will terminate sounds wrong enough that I thought I'd ask if anyone knows if that's a language requirement or not.

Comment: I think this question would be better suited to cstheory.stackexchange.com.

Comment: S := S is one correct answer. Clearly infinitely many grammars generate the empty language. What part of the definition of grammar does this grammar violate? None...

Comment: @Patrick87 the part I am hoping exists that states that it must be able to terminate?  That's the whole premise of the question!

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. So yeah, there is no such requirement, unfortunately. A necessary and sufficient condition equivalent to "there must be a way to terminate" is "grammars define non-empty languages".

Comment: @jwodder cstheory.stackexchange.com doesnt cover this kind of problem (research level only)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [Formal Grammar Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar):

> the language of G, denoted as L(G), is defined as all those sentences that can be derived in a finite number of steps from the start symbol S.

Starting with S, applying the production rule once to S gives S. Applying the rule twice gives S. By induction, applying the rule any finite number still gives S. Since no sentences can be derived in a finite number of steps, the language is empty, so your professor is correct.

Alternative ways to define a grammar that accepts the empty set are `L(G) = {}` (the language is empty) or `P = {}` (the set of production rules is empty).

Comment: You aren't required to accept an answer that you don't feel answers the question. If you want better quality answers you could try a bounty.

Comment: The only bad thing about this answer is that it flounders a little with irrelevant information. The answer is absolutely right: your professor is unambiguously correct, and his is an unambiguous set of productions for generating the empty language. Your accepting or failing to accept this answer won't change mathematics.

Comment: @Levi: He gave you a better answer:  The empty grammar (i.e. no production rules at all).

Comment: The key: "Since no [strings] can be derived in a *finite* number of steps the language is empty[...]" My natural inclination (and that of my peers) was to try to continually re-substitute and try again, meaning we forget the finite aspect of the problem.